# question about Stone Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$x$ is normal space and we recognize him by his picture in $βX$. show that every $c_1 c_2$, close and disjoint sets in $x$ also the closure of $c_1$ and $c_2$ (in the closure of $x$) is disjoint.

i tried to bulid the Stone Čech compactification and see where it takes me but i didnt know what to do with the closure.

Answer (score 1):

Use Urysohn's Lemma to get a continuous function to $[0,1]$ sending $c_1$ to $0$ and $c_2$ to $1$.  That function extends continuously to $\beta X$.

Comment: thank you! but i didnt understand how the closure of x connected to this equation. in which space can i discuss the closure of c1 and c2

Comment: Your original question answers your comment: The closures of $c_1$ and $c_2$ are to be formed in the closure of $X$, which is of course, in this case $\beta X$.

Comment: ok, that's was i figured, but how can i prove that the closure of x is compact hausdorff space? thanks in advanced.

Comment: That depends on how $\beta X$ is defined. The definition I'm accustomed to essentially includes the information that it's compact and has $X$ as a dense subspace.  But you might be using a different definition or construction, in which case these facts would have to be proved.  Presumably, whatever source you're using for a definition of $\beta X$ would also contain a proof (or at least a reference to a proof) of these basic properties.